# Stucture with array of pointers in C

Tags: c, sdl

What's wrong with this?  Can I have an array of pointers to SDL_Surfaces in a struct in C?

```
typedef struct {
    int next_wheel;
    int pos_X;
    int pos_Y;
    int front_wheel_pos_X;
    int front_wheel_pos_Y;
    int velocity;
    int rear_wheel_pos_X;
    int rear_wheel_pos_Y;
    SDL_Surface* body;
    SDL_Surface* rear_wheel[9];
    SDL_Surface* front_wheel[9];
} mars_rover;

...

mars_rover* init_rover() {
    mars_rover* rover = (mars_rover*)malloc(sizeof(mars_rover) + sizeof(SDL_Surface) * 19);
    rover->body = load_image("Graphics//rover.png", ds_info);
    rover->front_wheel[0] = load_image("Graphics//wheel//wheel0.png", ds_info);
    ...

    return rover;
}

int main() {
    mars_rover* rover = init_rover();
...
}
```

**EDIT:** added my load image function.

```
SDL_Surface *load_image( const char* filename , SDL_VideoInfo* ds_info) {

    SDL_Surface* image = 0;
    SDL_Surface* converted_surface = 0;
    image = IMG_Load(filename);

    if(image) {
        converted_surface = SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha(image);
        SDL_FreeSurface(image);
    }

    return converted_surface;
}
```

Comment: there's nothing bad in it, provided that you are initializing the pointers right

Comment: Nothing wrong with what you posted. What's the problem?

Comment: It causes strange behavior.  The SDL_Surfaces get blitted in the wrong places, or not at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but you need to assign an allocated memory for each pointer separately. So instead of:

```
mars_rover* rover = (mars_rover*)malloc(sizeof(mars_rover) + sizeof(SDL_Surface) * 19);
```

you should have:

```
mars_rover* rover = malloc(sizeof(mars_rover));
rover->body = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Surface));
for (i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    rover->rear_wheel[i] = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Surface));
    rover->front_wheel[i] = malloc(sizeof(SDL_Surface));
}
```

Two notes though:

1. You need to check the return value of each allocation
2. You need to free each of the allocation when you clean up

Comment: SDL handles the allocation in `IMG_Load(filename);`.

Comment: so in such case you shouldn't allocate for it at all, but in any case, the extra space you allocated for all the pointers + arrays is redundant.